# Does a Docker Hub require to upload the entire image every time I make a change?

Tags: docker

I was trying out Docker and I did the following:

1. Pulled an image called: `docker/whalesay`
2. Built another image with some minor changes.
3. Pushed it back in a different name to my public repository (Had to upload approximately the same size I downloaded).
4. I then built another image with this public image as the starting point.
5. Had only a single command. But again I had to upload the entire image back.

My question is, isn't Docker supposed to upload just the changes? I read it somewhere. It seems like I am making some stupid mistake, I can't believe that we have to upload the entire image everytime after minor changes. Am I missing something?

This is the `Dockerfile` I am using to build the image `fishsay`:

```
FROM docker/whalesay:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y fortunes
CMD /usr/games/fortune -a | cowsay
```

The whalesay image was ~180 MB; so when I push shouldn't I have to just upload the changed layers?

Comment: How are you building your other image? With a `Dockerfile` starting with `FROM docker/whalesay`?

Comment: What is the cmd use for build the image ?

Comment: `docker build -t fishsay .` from the directory that contains the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Any changes to a layer in your image would requires to be updated in the repository when you call the `docker push`. This could be a small and trivial such as including a new package (ex: vi) in your image. However, this would cause new layers to be created and replace the existing layers, causing different layer id's, from what is already in the registry. `docker push`  uploads all new layers created into the registry, excluding the base image.

Comment: I understand that; but isn't the subsequent layers added as an addition rather than being merged with previous layers and changed into something else, thus having to upload everything again?

Answer (score 0):

Me also facing same issue, what I have come to is

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18866#issuecomment-192770785
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14018

> As mentioned in above links this feature is implemented in Docker
>   Engine 1.10 / Registry 2.3.

And after email to docker support I got the following reply

> Hello,
>
> Unfortunately, we don't have any timelines for when updates to the
>   Docker Hub will happen that we can share publicly. Sorry for any
>   trouble caused by this.
>
> /Jeff